# Insert properties into last element in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

**EDIT** Sorry! This code actually works correctly; I was looking at the wrong error. Thanks to everyone for their input.

I want to be able to directly access the last element of a `vector<>` in C++. Currently, I `push_back()` a temporary variable (of a custom type), however I'd much rather put data straight into the vector. The following code is an example of what I'd like to do. It won't compile, but it does a better job of explaining than I do:

```
typedef struct
{
    float colour[3];
}
CustomType

vector<CustomType> customArray;

customArray.push_back(CustomType());

// The hard part - won't work
customArray.back().colour[0] = 1;
```

I'd like some help with the last line; what's the correct syntax to put data into the most-recently pushed back element in a vector?

Comment: That code compiles for me (once I've fixed the trivial syntax error - missing `;`).

Comment: I am not very sure about ur question but will this work for u 
customArray[customArray.size()-1].colour[0] = 1;

Comment: What do you mean it won't work?  As posted, the code works fine, since `customArray.back()` returns a reference to the last element, not a copy.

Comment: @Oli: It does for me too. Turns out I didn't read the error properly; it was for a different piece of code. Just out of interest, it's fine to use `.back()` in this context, right?

Comment: If you've answered your own question, you should probably just close/delete it...

Comment: I can't delete it, but yes, I'll close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why won't

```
customArray.back().colour[0] = 1;
```

work?

It does work! Try again :)

Answer (score 2):

`back()` returns a reference to the last item of the vector, your code is correct apart from a small syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

`customArray.size() - 1` is the index of the last item that was added to the vector

`customArray[customArray.size()-1].color[0]=1` should work.

[As Oli and interjay et al have commented, the `back()` method will work if you correct the syntax error]

Comment: `back()` should work as well, and is more readable.

Comment: After realising I'm an idiot, yes, `back()` is better to use. Thanks anyway, @jonsca.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
// Construct vector with `NUM_ELEMENTS` entries
vector<CustomType> customArray(NUM_ELEMENTS);

// Now you can access them directly
customArray[0].colour[0] = 1;
```

Comment: Exactly that, but I want to get the last element of the array, which is of a dynamic length. @jonsca has the right idea.

Comment: @Jam: Ok, but then why not just use `back()`?  It's less typing!

Comment: `back()` has been suggested a lot and I was actually using it correctly before - my code wasn't compiling due to another error, which I was getting confused with. In other news, less typing... I'm sold!